# Calculate Age from DateTime Field - Wordpress UserFrontEnd Pro

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am using the **UserFrontEnd Pro** plugin for my **Wordpress** website. I created a new Registration form, I added a DateTime field and an age field (age field should be uneditable), so what should happen is when the user selects a particular date, the age should be automatically calculated as soon as the user selects a date and display it in the age field.

So, basically age should be calculated and displayed as soon as the user selects a date.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you are using a Pro version, you can get decent support through them. See one of the testimonials: https://nimb.ws/JempZd :D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? You are expected to have researched your issue and made a good attempt to solve it before posting a question. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to see what we need, then update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help.